# Initializing variable in HTML5 for Input tag

Tags: html, angular-cli

Here is the html source code of page that loads array of products:

```
<div class="container" *ngFor="let product of products">
  <div class="product">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img
        //image url
    </div>
    <div class="product-info">
      <div class="product-content">
        <h1>{{product.name}}</h1>
        <p>{{product.description}}</p>
        <p>Price: {{product.price}} $</p>
        <p>Quantity:
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="minusQuantity(product)">-</button>
          <input type="number" class="input-quantity" [(ngModel)]="product.count"/>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="plusQuantity(product)">+</button>
        <div class="buttons">
          <a class="button add" (click)="addToCart(product)">Add to Cart</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When page is loaded, numeric input is empty (there is no value visible inside). Hence clicking on - and + buttons to invoke `minusQuantity()` and `plusQuantity()` have no effect on the product.count and displaying it on the page.

I've tried to set default value, but it is overridden by ngModel. If i use only value without ngModel, then input does not react to any changes caused by -/+ buttons (since it's just hardcoded "1").

But if I input e.g. "1" manually on the input, then + and - buttons do work, since there is a value provided, and it works OK.

Question is:

How avoid this issue? Is there any way to initialize input type with some value and then pass it to the product.count correctly? Or the approach should be totally different?

Fragments of components that handle +/- methods:

#### product.component.ts

```
plusQuantity(product: ProductModel) {
   if (product.count < 99) {
     this.cartService.increaseQuantity(product);
   }
 }

 minusQuantity(product: ProductModel) {
   if (product.count > 1) {
     this.cartService.decreaseQuantity(product);
   }
 }
```

#### cartService.ts

```
increaseQuantity(product: ProductModel) {
    product.count = product.count + 1;
    this.orderElement.quantity = product.count + 1;
    return product.count;
}

decreaseQuantity(product: ProductModel) {
    product.count = product.count - 1;
    this.orderElement.quantity = product.count - 1;
    return product.count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use a javascript file with the code:

```
var cartService = {}
cartService.plusQuantity = function(product) {
    product = ProductModel;
    if (product.count < 99) {
        this.cartService.increaseQuantity(product);
    }
};
cartService.minusQuantity = function(product) {
    product = ProductModel;
    if (product.count > 1) {
        this.cartService.decreaseQuantity(product);
    }
};
```

Then it might work!

Comment: Well this did not work... When loading the page with inputs and buttons, input value is still empty. What's more, buttons do not react now on clicking :(

Comment: When I said this I did not know a lot about websites. Now I have my own website! It's at http://currancodes.com/. I edited the awnser try it now.